# If $f$ is complex differentiable then so is $\bar{f}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Suppose $f$ is complex differentiable on some open set $U$, is $\bar{f}$ also differentiable?

Assuming $f'(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists does $\overline{f(z)}=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{\overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(z_0)}}{z-z_0}$ also exist?

Is this just properties of limits?

$\overline{f}'(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{\overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(z_0)}}{z-z_0}=\frac{\lim_{z\to z_0}\overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(z_0)}}{\lim_{z\to z_0} z-z_0}$

Then let $\epsilon >0$ by assumtion there exists $\delta >0$ s.t if $\vert z-z_0\vert <\delta$ then $\vert f(z)-f(z_0)\vert <\epsilon$

and $\vert f(z)-f(z_0)\vert=\vert \overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(z_0)}\vert<\epsilon$

so $\frac{\lim_{z\to z_0}\overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(z_0)}}{\lim_{z\to z_0} z-z_0}$ exists and $f'(z)=\overline{f'(z)}$?

Comment: $\bar f$ is complex differentiable iff $f$ is constant (assuming $f$ differentiable on a domain); the right function is $\overline {f(\bar z)}$ which is indeed differentiable when $f$ is and the domain works (contains $\bar z$ when it contains $z$)

Comment: Something is off. $\overline{f^{\prime}(z_0)}=\lim\frac{\overline{f(z)-f(z_0)}}{\overline{z-z_0}}$, but $\overline{f}^{\prime}(z_0)=\lim\frac{\overline{f(z)-f(z_0)}}{z-z_0}$, so the relationship isn't all that clear. Try to see what happens for the identity function $f(z)=z$:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $\overline{f}'(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{\overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(z_0)}}{z-z_0}=\frac{\lim_{z\to z_0}\overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(z_0)}}{\lim_{z\to z_0} z-z_0}$

You can't split the limits like that.

The property of limits says $$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{\displaystyle \lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)}{\displaystyle \lim_{z\to z_0} g(z)}$$ **as long as both limits on the RHS exists and  $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to z_0} g(z) \ne 0$**

> Then let $\epsilon >0$ by assumtion there exists $\delta >0$ s.t if $\vert z-z_0\vert <\delta$ then $\vert f(z)-f(z_0)\vert <\epsilon$
> and $\vert f(z)-f(z_0)\vert=\vert \overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(z_0)}\vert<\epsilon$

This proves that if $f$ is continuous so is $\overline{f}$.